# Subclassing pandas dataframe and setting field in constuctor

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to [subclass pandas data structure](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures). If I set a field on the instance, it works fine.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')

class Results(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # use the __init__ method from DataFrame to ensure
        # that we're inheriting the correct behavior
        super(Results, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return Results
    
result_object = Results(df)
result_object['scheme'] = 'not_default'
print(result_object.head(5))

>>>   sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width species       scheme
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa  not_default
1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa  not_default
2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa  not_default
3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa  not_default
4           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  setosa  not_default
```

I don't quite understand the `_constructor` method under the hood well enough to tell why this does not work.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')

class Results(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args,scheme='default', **kwargs):
        # use the __init__ method from DataFrame to ensure
        # that we're inheriting the correct behavior
        super(Results, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self['scheme'] = scheme

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return Results

result_object = Results(df.copy(),scheme='not_default')
print(result_object.head(5))

>>>
# scheme is still 'default'
   sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width species   scheme
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa  default
1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa  default
2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa  default
3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa  default
4           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  setosa  default
```

Notice the `scheme` field still says default.

Is there anyway to set a field in the instance constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current version creates `scheme` as an attribute (like `.index`, `.columns`):

```py
result_object.scheme

# 0      not_default
# 1      not_default
#           ...     
# 148    not_default
# 149    not_default
# Name: scheme, Length: 150, dtype: object
```

To make it a proper column, you can modify the incoming `data` before sending it to `super()`:

```py
class Results(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, data=None, *args, scheme='default', **kwargs):

        # add column to incoming data
        if isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame):
            data['scheme'] = scheme

        super(Results, self).__init__(data=data, *args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return Results

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
result_object = Results(df.copy(), scheme='not_default')

#    sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width species       scheme
# 0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa  not_default
# 1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa  not_default
# 2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa  not_default
# 3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa  not_default
# ...         ...          ...           ...          ...     ...          ...
```